# EMERGENCY I just deployed a change set and now one field has lost all data in production what do I do?

Tags: custom-field, delete

I have an agency field in accounts and for some reason after some recent updates the field seems to be blank for all accounts.  The field was not included in the change set and was not dependent on anything included.  What could have happened?  Is there a way for me to restore data to the way it was before the update or view the field's previous value?  Please help this is a major issue!!!

Comment: If you did not have field enabled its hard to get that data back unless you have backed up data .You may contact sfdc via a simple case and check but since its not data deletion and instead override there is some process like workflow or batch that modified your data .Remember deployment never changes or affects data and it affects only metadata .Also make sure to check if you have FLS properly set .

Comment: change set is non destructive and can't cause data loss.  Losing all the data in a field is really only.possible via a data load, or by changing the field type.   You should not be able to deploy a change in field type via change set, you should have to make that change in production.  Have you done any field type changes?